# Attempted import error: 'initializeApp' is not exported from 'firebase' (imported as 'firebase')

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How can we fix it

./src/firebase.js

> Attempted import error: 'initializeApp' is not exported from 'firebase' (imported as 'firebase').

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC_H_QFOOxAGFs2Nz4URaSRWD9VdLMBNE0",
    authDomain: "drugsreact.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://drugsreact-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "drugsreact",
    storageBucket: "drugsreact.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "575958955155",
    appId: "1:575958955155:web:9e42328794cbf3ada4c966"
  };
 
  // Initialize Firebase
  var fireDb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  export default fireDb.database().ref();
```

Comment: can you try `import * as firebase from firebase` see if that works

Answer (score 0):

This is due to firebase SDK having some changes in handling exports in it's new version 8.0.0

Try using this:

`import firebase from "firebase/app"`
instead of
`import firebase from 'firebase';`